# Calling a Batch File into a Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

Everytime my Powershellscript is calling the Batchfile, a new Powershell Window opens. How can i modify the script in order to avoid the new window opens? I've tried with -windowstyle hidden and NoNewWindow, but nothing works.

Here is the Batchfile that starts my Powershell Script:

```
@echo off

set scriptFileName=%~n0
set scriptFolderPath=%~dp0
set powershellScriptFileName=test.ps1

powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -Command "Start-Process powershell \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -Command `\"cd \`\"C:\Temp\`\"; & \`\".\test.ps1\`\"`\"\" -Verb RunAs"
```

And here is my Powershell Script:

```
$Source = "C:\Program Files\Planmeca\Romexis\client\cephmodule\analyses"

$Destination = "\\PRENCIPE-THINK\PDATA\analyses"  #<------ UNC PFAD FUER DEN SERVER ANPASSEN!!
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Destination -Force 
Copy-Item -Path $Source\*.* -Destination $Destination -Force -Recurse

(ROBOCOPY $Source $Destination /MIR /W:30 /R:10) 

# Ueberpruefe den Ordner auf veraenderungen
# Fuehre den Script aus bei Aenderung oder Umbennenung

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = 'C:\Program Files\Planmeca\Romexis\client\cephmodule\analyses'
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite -bor [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName

while($TRUE){
$result = $watcher.WaitForChanged([System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Changed -bor [System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Renamed -bOr [System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Created, 1000);
    if($result.TimedOut){
    continue;
}
write-host "Change in " + $result.Name
$A = Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden -FilePath c:\temp\Bypass.bat -Wait -passthru ;$a.ExitCode
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to run PowerShell with a bat file?

Comment: @JamesC. Yes, but you i'm open for improvements

Comment: @JamesC. I want to run PowerShell with a bat file, for i need to automatically copy the modified or new created files to the server.

Comment: What happens if you simplify your command a bit to just read `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "c:\Temp\test.ps1"`?

Comment: Your batch file doesn't do much. Your capturing parameters sent to it, but you don't appear to be using them? Why are you using a batch file instead of running powershell directly? How are you executing the batch file?

Comment: As already pointed out, just run the powershell script. The batch file does nothing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the '-NoNewWindow' switch.  I'm running PS Version 5.1 on Windows 7 and it's available.  If you're running an earlier iteration if WMF, you may want to update your machines to 5 or better.